# What is the best method for authorization Angular with asp.net Core?

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

I read about JWT, Asp Indentity , Indentity Server, Auth0, Oauth 2.
But i could not get what is the best approach should i take to authorize web site has many services may user buy only two of them or all services implemented by angular 7 for front end and asp.net core.
What is the best Approach for authorization?
How can i choose the best approach for any website authorization?
Is there any recommended Material "Books or Courses" should i learn to be good in similar problem?

Comment: I think this question will be closed soon (because  ppl will say that it's opinion based) :( . But my 2 cents of suggestion would be to check OAuth2.0 . This is pretty standard and you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc which is recommend by angular team as well. So it should be good enough. I am using the same in my proj . Check more about this on google

Comment: @ShashankVivek yes, I agree with you it is opinion based. for me the most suggestion was Identity server4 but I could not get  a clear answer why i should use one of those approach not the other. I will check the link ,thanks

Comment: Not making this an official answer because as discussed above, this should be closed. However, you should make the decision based on your needs and your current infrastructure. All solutions offer different pros and cons. The general trend is OAuth and JWT. Hope your search goes well

Comment: You may find this [article](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/) interesting.